# Example of context-free but non regular language with context-free complement

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar

As we know context-free languages are not closed under complement. But are there examples of non regular context-free languages which complement is context-free?

We know that regular languages is smallest class containing finite languages closed under sum, complement, concatenation and Kleene star. Context-free languages are similar but are not closed under complement. Does it mean that there are no such language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Deterministic context-free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_context-free_language) are closed under complement.

Answer (score 1):

An example: $\{a^n b^n: n \geq 0\}$; you can check that the complement is context-free by writing it as an appropriate union.